# How to get the name of an aliased expression in polars?

Tags: python-polars

Suppose I have a polars expression in python. Is there a straightforward way to get information about it? For example, if an expression is an alias, how might I get the name?

```py
import polars as pl

pl.col("mpg").alias("mpg2")
```

I've looked through the different methods both on polars Expr and PyExpr classes, but had trouble finding anything that returned information about an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polars expression have a `meta` namespace that allows you to get meta information about expressions.

```py
>>> pl.col("mpg").alias("mpg2").meta.output_name()
'mpg2'
```

Comment: Ah thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm realizing nothing under meta seems to give the expression method name (e.g. alias). I can .pop() to get an expression's arguments, but not the name of the expression itself...). Is this meta information present somewhere?

Comment: What would define the extressions name? You could call .__str__()

Comment: I was thinking of just the word "alias", since `str()` gives you "alias" mixed in with the stringified contents of `.meta.pop()`.

Comment: You would need to write a regex match for that. An expression cannot be composed of only alias, it needs an input expression.